# Access Plugin Public Method inside Velocity Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity

I would like to access a Public Method of my Plugin inside the Progress Function of Velocity. But i can't get it working

This Method creates Elements with Public Functions

```
var animateFeed = function (ms) {
    var i = 0;
    var animationInterval = setInterval(function () {
        if (_tempelements.length > 0) {
            var shiftedElement = _tempelements.shift();

            shiftedElement.feedseed({
                stage: '.socialfeeds',
                stageElm: '.feed-post',
                id: i++,
                y: helper.randInt(0, 150),
                speed: helper.randInt(20, 120),
                scale: helper.randFloat(0.4, 1.01)
            });
            socialfeedObject.push(shiftedElement);
        }
    }, ms);
};
```

This Plugin also returns some Public Methods

```
$.fn.feedseed = function (options) {
    // default settings
    var settings = $.extend({
        element: this,
        stage: '',
        stageElm: '',
        id: 0,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 0,
        startX: 0,
        scale: 1.0,
        speed: 100
    }, options);

    // some more code here...

    // Public Function
    this.play = function () {
        if (!OBJ.isRunning) {
            OBJ._then = Date.now();
            frame();
            OBJ.isRunning = true;
        }
        return this;
    };

    // Public Function
    this.pause = function () {
        cancelAnimationFrame(OBJ.rafid);
        OBJ.isRunning = false;
        return this;
    };

    this.seek = function (multiplier) {
        settings.speed = settings.speed * multiplier;
        return this;
    };
};
```

At this Point i need to access the Seek Function of my Plugin inside Velocity, but how to get this working?

```
$('.speedup').on('click tap', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < socialfeedObject.length; i++) {
        socialfeedObject[i].velocity({
            tween: [1, 200]
        }, {
            duration: 600,
            easing: 'easeOutQuad',
            progress: function(elements, complete, remaining, start, tweenValue) {
                // ?
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. If i set the Public Method this way, it works now for me.

```
$.fn.feedseed.seek = function (multiplier) {
  // do something
};
```